# Heroku Local: "http" directive is duplicate

Tags: heroku, nginx

I'm running into the following issue when running `heroku local`:

`[emerg] 595#0: "http" directive is duplicate in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17`

I've got `heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"` in my composer.json, and a fresh install of nginx (using `brew install nginx`)

Could someone explain to me what could be happening?

Comment: What is line 17 of your `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Comment: It's an http directive, but there's only one occurence of it in that .conf though.
This is the nginx.conf that comes with a fresh nginx install: http://pastebin.com/zBbUUPC7

Comment: Is there an include directive which loads say `*.conf` and maybe pulling the file in more than once?

Comment: I think there might be some conflict between the nginx default config file and the one heroku creates.
This is the script heroku local seems to run to generate a nginx config, which by itself doesn't seem to work (missing events section): https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it seems the problem is related to the `heroku.conf` generated by `$root/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php`

`Heroku local` runs nginx with `nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off; include $root/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf;`

So both `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `heroku.conf` are loaded, hence the duplicate directive.

I've modified `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to only include

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
```

since without the events section nginx won't start, and left the rest to `heroku.conf`.